# Is there an algorithm to check how similar are two 2d data sets?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, equality, similarity

I need help
First of all, I'm not looking if the 2 data sets are equal (A==B), or if the have similar features, because they are similar.

I have two 2D data sets (there are actually 2 vector fields), one is 'fixed' and the other is 'experimental', I want to know **HOW MUCH** equal they are. My thought is to get a number per point who say if they are equal in a range of values (0 to 1, including decimals). That is for make an iterative algorithm to find the best experimental data set who agrees with the fixed one... but first I need to find "*how much equal they are*"

It's like measure the error to minimize it

Comment: Please share a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: Use the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of `|a-b|` where `a \in A, b \in B` pairwise?

Comment: @Neil I feel so dumb xd, thank's for your answer, I will try that: a new array that show the error

Comment: _Nb_ that it works if `|A|=|B|` and all the data mapped to the same location; otherwise, more complicated models will probably need to be considered. Depends on your data.

Comment: For most vectors a typical measure is root-mean-squared error. That works for 2D arrays too. But do you care about any other similarities besides same-cell? e.g. if they are images, say, you might want to be less sensitive to exact position alignment or might allow small rotations also. More generally, if there is a meaning to the X and Y axes you might want a different similarity measure.

Answer (score 0):

If one has `|A| = |B|` and the same (or close) sample points, one could use simply the standard deviation of each pair of `|a-b|`, where `a \in A`, `b \in B`, pairwise. One doesn't need a separate temporary array if you use a stable, on-line algorithm like [Welford's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_online_algorithm), (just take the square root at the end to get the standard deviation.)